# Line break in javascript after random numbers

Tags: javascript

I know that is very simple, but why is the line break not working here and the numbers keep printing in a single line? I want to print 100 random numbers on a line and then again 100 random numbers, but on a new line.

```js
function generateNumber() {

  const arr = Array(100)

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    setInterval(() => {
      let randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      document.write(randomNumber + "\n")
    }, 3000);

  }
}

function test() {
  generateNumber();
}

test();
```

Comment: You need to use `<br>` instead of `\n` to add a line break in HTML

Comment: i'm sorry, but if i put <br> it will print me into a column 100 numbers,  i wanna like this one: 22323232323  /n 4650569568

Comment: So what is the criteria for the line break? I first thought that a line break should happen each 10 digits, but that might not be the case since the first number is 11 digits and the second number is 10 digits. It might be a typo and the first number should also be 10 digits.

Comment: @MichaelV should each row also have 100 numbers? So in total, 100 lines, with each line containing 100 numbers? Where each line is generated 3s apart from each other? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @NickParsons yep, - > after 100 random number a new line with a new 100 random numbers

Comment: @MichaelV and how many lines total? 100? Or infinite...?

Comment: doesn't matter i think

Answer (score 3):

Try putting `<br>` instead of `\n`.

**Edit:** I just saw your comment explaining you want 100 digits on each line. Try this:

```
function generateNumber() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}

function test() {
  generateNumber();
}

test();
setInterval(test, 3000);
```

**Second edit:** it seems from your code you want this to run every three seconds, so I have added the setInterval line to the end above. If you don't want that, remove that line.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you actually want?

```js
setInterval(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  document.write("<br>");
}, 1000);
```